# Ubuntu 12.04 forgetting XModmap settings often

Tags: 12.04, xmodmap, lock

I have the following contents in my ~/.Xmodmap file.  It seems a couple times a day (without rebooting or logging out) I need to rerun the command "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" to reset my settings.  The only thing I can think is that it seems to happen when I walk away from my computer for a bit.  Maybe it forgets the settings when the computer locks itself?

```
remove control = Control_L
remove mod1 = Alt_L
keycode 64 = Control_L
keycode 37 = Alt_L
add control = Control_L
add mod1 = Alt_L
```

Anyone else seeing similar issues?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** I did some more research and it turns out this was because I had my USB keyboard plugged into my monitor's USB port. Simply plugging my keyboard into the back of computer fixed it.  I guess when the monitor turns back on Ubuntu sees it as a new keyboard and doesn't feel the need to re-apply the .Xmodmap settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing.  It's driving me nuts.  If anybody can figure out why this is happening, please let us know!

Update: I found this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8419110

It seems there's an interaction between xkb and xmodmap that's making the xmodmap settings get lost.  I don't know anything about xkb, but it seems that that is the thing we're supposed to do now.

Comment: I solved this issue on my end. Hopefully the same applies to your problem. If your keyboard is plugged into the monitor, switch it out to the PC.